# While clicking on button progress ring is not visible

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have 1 button in my main grid.On clicking the button i m changing the view of child grid, say on 1st click i am displaying 1 list view and on second click i m displaying 1 grid view with diff data.while changing the view i want to show progress ring as it's taking time to load the data.i have done 1 thing is on button click just show progress indicator and after loading is done just dismiss the progress indicator.but it's not working.any idea?

Answer (score 1):

that is because all your execution is being done on single thread without any breaks for UI to actually render the view.

Split the logic into 3 parts

1) Start animation

2) push this code in Task.Run and await on it.

3) End animation